# In how many ways can I randomly pick a number of fruits such that there is two of each variety?

Tags: statistics

Suppose that I have $9$ bananas, $11$ apples, and $13$ oranges and I want to make a cake with $6$ of these fruits. If I were to randomly select the $6$ fruits that I need for the cake, what is the number of ways that will result in picking $2$ fruits of each variety, i.e., how many ways are there to randomly select a set of fruits that contains at least $2$ bananas, $2$ apples, and $2$ oranges.

I was able to calculate the number of possible ways of randomly selecting $6$ fruits as follows $${33 \choose 6 } = 1107568 $$ Thus, there are $1107568$ ways of picking 6 random fruits. I figured that I could calculate the number of ways of obtaining $2$ of each variety if I were to subtract the number of outcomes where there is not at least $2$ of one fruit for all cases, i.e., $$ 1107568- {{9 \choose 1} \cdot {11 \choose 5} \cdot {13 \choose 0}} - \ldots $$

Above I am subtracting all the possible ways where $1$ banana, $5$ apples, and $0$ oranges are picked. I think that this is impractical since it takes considerable time to do so (by hand at least) and maybe it is an invalid approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick the two particular bananas you want:  ${9 \choose 2}$.  Pick the two particular apples you want:  ${11 \choose 2}$.  Pick the two particular oranges you want:  ${13 \choose 2}$.

So the total is:

$$N = {9 \choose 2}{11 \choose 2}{13 \choose 2} = \frac{9 \cdot 8}{2}\frac{11 \cdot 10}{2}\frac{13 \cdot 12}{2} = 154440.$$

Comment: Would this be the case for picking each fruit out of the set that contains the $33$ fruits?

Comment: Yes.  You can make $36$ unique pairs of bananas, $65$ unique pairs of apples, and $78$ unique pairs of oranges from your particular $33$ pieces of fruit.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what would be the number of ways to pick the fruits such that they are all of the same variety? i.e., all apples, all bananas, or all oranges.

Comment: That's a separate question, but add up the number of ways to make $6$ of each fruit:  ${9 \choose 6} + {11 \choose 6} + {13 \choose 6}$.